# Compiling nginx module with dependant library

Tags: mysql, c, nginx

I have followed the tutorial here to build a simple nginx module with success: https://github.com/perusio/nginx-hello-world-module

I can build and run that code with no issue and it functions correctly.

I now want to add a dependancy of MySQL to the simple nginx module so I have used the MySQL C Connector http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/c-api-building-clients.html.

The simplest program you can write is this (taken from http://zetcode.com/db/mysqlc/):

mysql_test.c

```
#include <my_global.h>
#include <mysql.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv) 
{
  printf("MySQL client version: %s\n", mysql_get_client_info());  
  exit(0);
}
```

You then compile like so:

```
$ gcc mysql_test.c -o mysql_test  `mysql_config --cflags --libs`
```

This works fine.

Now, when I try to include the two header files `my_global.h` and `mysql.h` with my simple nginx hello-world module, I need a way of specifying those build flags, else it won't find those header files. At the moment, when I run `make`, after it successfully builds all other modules, I now get:

```
cc -c -pipe  -O -W -Wall -Wpointer-arith -Wno-unused-parameter -Werror -g   -I src/core -I src/event -I src/event/modules -I src/os/unix -I objs -I src/http -I src/http/modules -I src/mail \
        -o objs/addon/nginx-hello-world-module/ngx_http_hello_world_module.o \
        /vagrant/nginx-hello-world-module/ngx_http_hello_world_module.c
/vagrant/nginx-hello-world-module/ngx_http_hello_world_module.c:33:23: fatal error: my_global.h: No such file or directory
 #include <my_global.h>
                       ^
compilation terminated.
make[1]: *** [objs/addon/nginx-hello-world-module/ngx_http_hello_world_module.o] Error 1
make[1]: Leaving directory `/vagrant/nginx'
make: *** [build] Error 2
```

My question is: How do I get nginx to include those build flags when building my module?

I haven't found any information regarding the building of dependencies with Nginx.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

> **Compilation Controls**
>
> **--with-cc-opt**=*parameters*
>   sets additional parameters that will be added to the CFLAGS variable.
>
> **--with-ld-opt**=*parameters*
>   sets additional parameters that will be used during linking.

[Source](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/installoptions/)

For the MySQL Connector C it will be something like:

```
--with-cc-opt="-I/usr/include/mysql"
--with-ld-opt="-L/usr/lib64/mysql"
```

And in you module's `config` file:

```
CORE_LIBS="$CORE_LIBS -lmysqlclient"
```

During compilation it might also complain about `_GNU_SOURCE` being redefined and it will fail if you use `-Werror` without implementing a workaround.